# After calling a method, I'm getting a null value for my array list

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arraylist

```
showMainMenu();
            mainChoice = input.nextInt();

            switch(mainChoice){

            case 1 :    showConcertCategories();
                        concertCategories = input.nextInt();

                        switch(concertCategories){

                        case 1 :    showMusical();
                                    musical = input.nextInt();

                                    switch(musical){

                                    case 1 :    showMyFairLady();
                                                myFairLady = input.nextInt();

                                                switch(myFairLady){

                                                case 1 :    System.out.print("Please input number of tickets:");
                                                            title = "MY FAIR LADY";
                                                            date = "20/01/08";
                                                            tickets = input.nextInt();
                                                            totalPrice = 90 * tickets;

                                                            System.out.println("\nBooking Information <All concerts begin at 8pm>");
                                                            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
                                                            System.out.println("Concert:        MY FAIR LADY");
                                                            System.out.println("Length:         135 minutes");
                                                            System.out.println("Date:           20/01/08");
                                                            System.out.println("Number of tickets:  "+tickets);
                                                            System.out.println("Price per ticket:   $90.00");
                                                            System.out.println("Total:          $"+fmt.format(totalPrice));
                                                            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
                                                            System.out.println("<1>Confirm");
                                                            System.out.println("<2>Redo");
                                                            System.out.print("Please select your choice<1-2>:");
                                                            confirmRedo = input.nextInt();

                                                            switch(confirmRedo){

                                                            case 1 :    System.out.println("\n************************************");
                                                                        System.out.println("* Your ticket(s) is/are confirmed. *");
                                                                        System.out.println("************************************");
                                                                        confirmation[0]=""+title;
                                                                        confirmation[1]=""+date;
                                                                        confirmation[2]=""+tickets;
                                                                        confirmation[3]=""+totalPrice;
                                                                        break;

                                                            case 2 :    showRedo();
                                                                        break;

                                                            default:    System.out.println("\nPlease select a valid choice.");
                                                            }
                                                }
                                                break;

                                    default:    System.out.println("\nPlease select a valid choice.");
                                    }
                                    break;

                        case 2 :    showClassical();
                                    break;

                        case 3 :    showPopMusic();
                                    break;

                        case 4 :    break;

                        default:    System.out.println("\nPlease select a valid choice.");
                        }
                        break;

            case 2 :    System.out.println("\nThank you for using this service.\n");
                        System.out.println("Concert             Date            Tickets         Total(S$)");
                        System.out.println("-----------         --------        ---------       -----------");
                        System.out.println(""+confirmation[0]+"         "+confirmation[1]+"         "+confirmation[2]+"         "+confirmation[3]);
                        break;

            default:    System.out.println("\nPlease select a valid choice.");
            }
```

Hi guys.. I have a problem with my code for my assignment.

Basically I was tasked to create a Booking Ticket program which after you have selected your desired options and exit the Main Menu, it will show you the summary of your confirmed booked tickets.

The part where I have a problem lies in the <2>Redo option as I'm not getting any value after calling showRedo();

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: "I'm not getting any value" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Try to reduce the code to a minimal excerpt showing the problem, no one wants to read that much code and figure out for you whats going on

Comment: Can you explain your question more clearly? Specifically, what does "I'm not getting any value after calling showRedo()" mean? Not getting a value where? What are you expecting to see, and how is it different from what you see?

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code. Can you give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so it's easier to help you?

Comment: Ok I've switched to switch-case method and hope it helps.
"showRedo" basically starts the process from "showConcertCategories" all over again and all the way down until I hit exit. However, after "redo-ing", the array value shows up null.

Answer (score 1):

Your showRedo()

```
    concertCategories = input.nextInt();

    if(concertCategories==1){
```

Only handles input if it's equal to 1. You don't have a case to handle input 2 and 3.

You should also look into using a Java Switch statement instead of this big nasty if-else ladder.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: If there will only ever be 1-3 choices if statements would be fine, if there might be more items in the future, the switch is the way to go. IMHO it is the level of nesting that is the problem. I would solve it by having a database of show info and submethods to handle each sub choice. It would DRY up a lot of the code.

Comment: @yonitdm There are a /lot/ of problems with the way this is structured, but I'm sure this is a more intro class to java and I don't think it helps to overwhelm him at this point.

Comment: I weighed that before replying (hence as a comment rather than an answer). The benefit to beginners using DRY code is that it makes tracing and debugging easier than a wall of text. Changing to a switch would not improve the code without other changes. Start em young I say :)

Comment: I've switched to switch-case but I don't quite get your solution...

Comment: @shinichi Your showRedo() method seems to be missing from your question now. But my point was that inside of your showRedo() method you weren't handling any input except for the value of 1. If a user put in 2 or 3, there was no code to act on those values. Everything would just fall through.

Comment: @shinichi If I remember correctly you had like if(input is 1) then do this, but you never had if(input is 2) then do this, if(input is 3) then do this, etc.